# How can I configure Cloudflare DNS on my VPS for optimal networking performance?

Tags: networking, dns, cloudflare, vps

## Cant open web application even though DNS is resolved

I have 2 virtual machine (VM) on VPS with dedicated ip public each vm's and each vm had ip private.
I use VPN to remote VM.

Let say a.domain.com and b.domain.com

I managed domain.com with cloudflare. In cloudflare, I have pointed each sub domain to each ip public

a.domain.com to xx.xx.xx.xx
b.domain.com to yy.yy.yy.yy

Then i checked on dnschecker.org, the result is resolved.

For couple months, I can access my subdomain on web browser properly.

But suddenly, all my website can't access using web browser.
I checked dnscheker.org, result is normal (resolved)
I ping to ip public, result is reply
I ping to subdomain (a.domain.com and b.domain.com), result is reply with right ip.
I traceroute to subdomain, result is reach ip public.

Than tried to access from other PC and other internet provider, result  still same (i cant access my website)

I thought my web service is down. Than I browse using ip private (connect VPN first), result : its work properly, my website work normally.

I called VPS provider, they said that nothings wrong with their network.

Can someone explain this please? Am I miss things in configuration.

Please explain this matter

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as the dns tag explains: DNS QUESTIONS MUST BE PROGRAMMING RELATED. Use this tag for programming questions related to writing code that interacts with the Domain Name System (DNS); for example, writing code that uses gethostbyname()